# (persistence) Entity Manager can not be created

Tags: java, servlets, jpa, persistence

I am having this problem and its 2 days I can not figure out why is happening.
I want to verify login. My code:

```
public String Verify(String name, String password) {
String admin="";
    Query q = emf
            .createEntityManager()
            .createQuery(
                    "SELECT u FROM user u where u.name = :name and u.password=:password");
    q.setParameter("name", name);
    q.setParameter("password", password);
    User u = (User) q.getSingleResult();

    if (u.getAdmin().equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
        admin = "yes";
    } else {
        admin = "no";
    }

    return admin;
}
```

I am getting this error then:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at db.DbProcessor.Verify(DbProcessor.java:19)
at controller.VerifikoServlet.doGet(VerifikoServlet.java:25)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Line 19 is ".createEntityManager()"

Comment: **Debugging** and **logging** always helps -- otherwise your `EntityManagerFactory` may not be initialized. Even you can split up your code, then you will see that which step is null.

Comment: Where and how is "emf" which I am guessing is an EntityManagerFactory instantiated? Looks like it might be null... Are you using some dependency injection perhaps?

Comment: it is not helping very much in this case :) however how can I initialize that?

Comment: @PersistenceContex ...... .. ..                                                     private EntityManagerFactory emf;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem writing this for initializing the Entity Factory Manager:

```
private static EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence
        .createEntityManagerFactory("PROJECT_NAME");
EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have not initialized your `EntityManagerFactory`. As I can see, you are running in Servlet environment.

Look at this link, it may be useful for you to read that: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/ss141213/archive/2005/12/dont_use_persis_1.html

Comment: yes I can get it, to explain further I am using persistence in a class and then I am calling this class methods from the servlets. I will try and I will respond back :)

Answer (score 0):

If the persistence layers are loaded are not this thing we can verify by simply adding the below code :
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
public class JpaUtil { 
    private static final EntityManagerFactory emf;

```
static {
    try {
        factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MyPu");
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        logger.error("Initial SessionFactory creation failed", ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}
```

...

}

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Please not this is a common stuff to get the entity Manager Factory Object. But here what is important is the Exception Handling inside that i.e. ExceptionInInitializerError ...

This will clearly tell if there is any problem related to your Entity classes like the missing TemporalType for a Date type variable or like that.

So if suppose you are using a NamedQuery in your entity class but even though since the persistence will not be able to load it because of any missing type or required property (like TemoralType for Date type) in your entity class.

so Make sure you handle the Exception mentioned